# How can I convert this AJAX structure to use .done instead of success:

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have a situation where a date, which is passed to an AJAX call, equals 'today' the first time the page is requested, and changes as the user uses the date picker.

I am using Jonathan Peterson's Bootstrap datetimepicker

https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker

It works fine - after some help from stackoverflow.

I constructed my code based on this article:

http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/ajax-deferreds

The solution in the article calls a function (buildActivityCount below) to work with the data from success:

My question is: Can the code below be re-written to use .done instead of success: ?  The code currently works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var buildActivityCount = function (data) {
     // construct some html with the data and add to div
  }


   // This is the call when the datepicker is used

   $("#dpDashboard").on("dp.change", function (e) {

      fromDate = moment(e.date).format("DD-MM-YYYY");

      var ajaxOptions = {
             type: "POST",
             dataType: "json",
             url: "/Main/activityCount",
             data: { fromDate: fromDate },
             success: buildActivityCount
      }

      $.ajax(ajaxOptions);


  });

  // This is the call when the page first loads:

  var fd = new Date();
  var fromDate = moment(fd).format("DD-MM-YYYY");

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/Main/activityCount",
    data: { fromDate: fromDate },
    success: buildActivityCount
  });

  $.ajax(ajaxOptions);

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Use `.done(...)` instead of passing in `success`.

Comment: `$.ajax(ajaxOptions).done(buildActivityCount);`
 and  
`$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/Main/activityCount",
    data: { fromDate: fromDate }
  }).done(buildActivityCount);`

Answer (score 1):

Yes quite easily. Remove the success from your options and add `.done()` after the ajax call

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      var buildActivityCount = function (data) {
      // construct some html with the data and add to div
      }
      // This is the call when the datepicker is used
      $("#dpDashboard").on("dp.change", function (e) {
          fromDate = moment(e.date).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
          var ajaxOptions = {
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              url: "/Main/activityCount",
              data: { fromDate: fromDate }
          }
      $.ajax(ajaxOptions).done(buildActivityCount);
      });
      // This is the call when the page first loads:
      var fd = new Date();
      var fromDate = moment(fd).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          url: "/Main/activityCount",
          data: { fromDate: fromDate }
      });
      $.ajax(ajaxOptions).done(buildActivityCount);
  }
```